# How to do parse xml file with XSD in python using minidom parser

Tags: python

I want to parse XML file in python and it should be validated against XSD as well. I have already used minidom for parsing XML file when I added XSD to header of XML seems like its not all validating XML against XSD.

Can you please let me know how to achieve this using minidom??

Waiting for your reply

Comment: You might consider using lxml instead of minidom.  lxml is capable of validating against [XSD](http://lxml.de/validation.html).

Comment: so you mean to say that minidom does not have the capability to validate against XSD???? Will lxml return a doc element like minidom does, so that I can just use lxml for xsd validation and will not changes rest of my code

Comment: I'm not an expert with minidom, but I don't believe it's capable of XSD validation.  It should be able to parse any properly formed XML, though.  You might find doing the same job with lxml simpler, and the lxml validator can validate your xml using your xsd and report where data is not valid.  Even if you don't use it, I would suggest going to the lxml link I gave and taking a look around.

Answer (score 0):

As the name suggests, miniDom is a library for interacting with the [Document Object Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) (DOM) API. As wikipedia states:

> The Document Object Model (DOM) is a cross-platform and language-independent convention for representing and interacting with objects in HTML, XHTML and XML documents.

It doesn't focus on the "validity" of the document, just that it is well-formed and able to be parsed and browsed.

As such, miniDom won't have any XML validation capability as this is beyond the scope of the DOM API.